# Аннотации в java и как они отображаются в памяти?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8

Правильно ли я понимаю, что аннотации это как маркерный класс, мета информация, и пометив класс своей аннотацией я не могу получить эти значения без рефлексии.
@Retention: в каком жизненном цикле кода аннотация будет доступна (в исходнике, в class-файле или во время выполнения)

То есть есть аннотации которые обрабатываются во время компиляции, например override.
А вот как понять class-файле или во время выполнения, в одном случае в память класса добавляется мета информация? И как в рантайме она появляется?
Можно посоветовать хорошие статьи по теме аннотации (рефлексия).

Comment: Почитайте пожалуйста тут http://www.seostella.com/ru/article/2012/05/19/annotacii-v-java-vvedenie.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Правильно ли я понимаю, что аннотации это как маркерный класс, мета
> информация, и пометив класс своей аннотацией я не могу получить эти
> значения без рефлексии.

Рефлексия в Java осуществляется с помощью Java Reflection API. ... reflexio — обращение назад) — это механизм исследования данных о программе **во время её выполнения.**

Так вот не все аннотации доступны в Runtime, а только которая помечена @Retention RUNTIME

Возможные типы аннотации:

- SOURCE - аннотация доступна только в исходном коде и сбрасывается во время создания .class файла;
- CLASS - аннотация хранится в .class файле, но недоступна во время выполнения программы;
- RUNTIME - аннотация хранится в .class файле и доступна во время выполнения программы.

Comment: CLASS - аннотация хранится в .class файле, но недоступна во время выполнения программы; для чего она тогда?

Comment: @Venot CLASS - используйте этот тип если хотите добавить какие-то характеристики к классам (например, создать список классов, которые используют аннотацию) до выполнения программы;